# There is any way to do a partial specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Just for fun I'm trying to implement a compile-time pow2 function with templates.
Actually, I'm able to do it, this way:

```cpp
template <std::size_t n, typename type_t>
struct custom
{
    static type_t pow(type_t b) { return b * custom<n - 1, type_t>::pow(b); }
};

template <typename type_t>
struct custom<0, type_t>
{
    // (void)b; to avoid unused warning.
    static type_t pow(type_t b) { (void) b; return static_cast<type_t>(1); }
};
```

And that way, it works, but my aproach was to think in something more like this:

```cpp
template <std::size_t n, typename type_t>
type_t cus_pow(type_t b) { return b * cus_pow<n - 1, type_t>(b); }

// This doesn't exists.
template <0, typename type_t>
type_t cus_pow(type_t b) { (void) b; return 1; }
```

Because if I want to create any partial metaprogramming function, beeing forced to create a struct it looks too much.

So, there is any way to do partial metaprogramming just with one function?

Comment: You cannot do partial specialization with function templates.

Comment: If you want a compile time `pow` calculation, you can just use a `constexpr` function with a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot partially specialize function/method.

You can use `if constexpr` (C++17) to avoid repetition though:

```
static type_t pow([[maybe_unused]]type_t b) {
    if constexpr (n == 0) {
        return static_cast<type_t>(1); }
    } else {
        return b * custom<n - 1, type_t>::pow(b);
    }
}
```

No extra runtime branching.

Answer (score 2):

> So, there is any way to do partial metaprogramming just with one function?

No: you can't partial specialize a template function.

But there are other ways to go around the problem.

If you can use C++17, an elegant solution is the use of `if constexpr` (see Jarod42's answer).

Before C++17, you can use SFINAE

```
template <std::size_t n, typename type_t>
std::enable_if_t<n == 0u, type_t> cus_pow (type_t)
 { return 1; }

template <std::size_t n, typename type_t>
std::enable_if_t<n != 0u, type_t> cus_pow (type_t b)
 { return b * cus_pow<n - 1, type_t>(b); }
```

to enable/disable version zero or version not zero, according the value of `n` (and define (or, at least, declare) the zero version *before*, given that the non-zero version can call it).

Another solution can be tag dispatching

```
template <std::size_t, typename type_t>
type_t cus_pow (std::true_type, type_t)
 { return 1; }

template <std::size_t n, typename type_t>
type_t cus_pow (std::false_type, type_t b)
 { return b * cus_pow<n-1u, type_t>(std::integral_constant<bool, n-1u==0u>{}, b); }

template <std::size_t n, typename type_t>
type_t cus_pow (type_t b)
 { return cus_pow<n>(std::integral_constant<bool, n==0u>{}, b); }
```

invoking another function with a "tag" (`std::true_type` or `std::false_type`) that say if `n` is zero or not.

Comment: In older C++ versions, you can also make the function a thin wrapper around a helper class, and the helper class CAN be partially specialized.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Yes: is the solution (`custom` struct) that the OP originally used. But remain a class/struct, not function, partial specialization.